# About using Windows 2016 physical server iscsi with vmware on Windows 10

Tags: vmware-workstation, iscsi

I am using iscsi on a Windows 2016 physical server. The Windows 2016 physical server has a vmware workstation installed and is running Windows 10 as an image. Windows 10 uses iscsi from 2016 Physical Server. However, when rebooting the Windows 2016 physical server, iscsi does not automatically connect on Windows 10. Windows 2016 physical server iscsi comes up as connecting. No matter how long you wait, no change.
I disconnected and reset the iscsi on the virtual image Windows 10. The connection is then. Can you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of VMware Workstation. It needs to be V15.5

You can use the default disk type for the Windows 10 Virtual Machine.

Also make a different Windows 10 guest system, see if another machine connects properly.